# Best way to dynamically set an array of substructs in a struct based on a variable size?

Tags: c++, struct

If my title is not very clear, I appologize. I have two c++ structs:

```
// SUB STRUCT
typedef struct {
        uint16_t trackID;
        uint16_t targetID;
} tracked_obj_t;

// MAIN STRUCT 
typedef struct
{
    uint16_t numberTrackedObj;  
    std::array<tracked_obj_t, /*numberTrackedObj*/> trackObj;
} dataMessage;
```

I want to be able to set the size of the array to the numTrackedObj variable thats in the struct- but I understand this is not possible because its not a const size variable. Is there a best way to approach this without using an outside struct variable for sizing?

Comment: You need `std::vector<tracked_obj_t>`. I'm not sure what the last sentence of your question means, but if you really really need to you can get away with `std::unique_ptr<tracked_obj_t[]>` and `std::make_unique<tracked_obj_t[]>(numberTrackedObj)` as well.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thank you.

Comment: *I have two c++ structs:* -- But you use `C`-syntax when declaring them.  In C++, there is no need for `typedef struct` -- just `struct nameOfStruct { stuff };` is necessary.